# how to validation empty textbox when button click wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I'm new in wpf and i want to make validation with error message on any empty text box user left when he click button to store data to database. I tried this in View Model. But its showing same message (Please enter all the scan details) for all field. is this ways is correct? or any other way is there to get Changed particular Message (like: Please enter the Name!) for each textbox? and how to focus that empty particular textbox? 
Please help.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Mode) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Url) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter all the scan details first.", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                SaveModelToDatabase();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved!", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look about the [IDataErrorInfo](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/784331/wpf-mvvm-validation-viewmodel-using-idataerrorinfo)